# How to recount number in each class from a read csv

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, count, match

I have a CSV where the the 6th column represents a count of the number of pupils in that class. I also have a separate piece of code which removes some pupils from the classes if they appear on a different script, how would I go about re counting the number of pupils in each class. See example data below:

```
Jan-20,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,more data....
Jan-20,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,more data....
Jan-20,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,more data....
Jan-20,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,more data....
Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,12,more data....
Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,12,more data....
Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,12,more data....
Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,12,more data....
Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,12,more data....
Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,12,more data....
Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,12,more data....
Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,12,more data....
Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,12,more data....
Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,12,more data....
Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,12,more data....
Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,12,more data....
Jan-50,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,6,more data....
Jan-50,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,6,more data....
Jan-50,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,6,more data....
Jan-50,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,6,more data....
Jan-50,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,6,more data....
Jan-50,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,6,more data....
```

The column that identifies which rows are deleted is over in 'more data' however upon any one row being deleted, how do I code to count the number of  pupils left in that class, essentially count column 2 and replace the value in column 6. (these class names are all unique)

I hope this makes sense. Any help would be gratefully received! Kind regards AEA

**EDIT**
With the above data saved as AEAtest.csv

I tried running the following code:

```
import csv
import itertools
from operator import itemgetter
import random

def some_condition(line):
    return random.random() < 0.5 # delete lines randomly with 50% probability

def filter_data(data):
    for classname, group in itertools.groupby(data, itemgetter(2)):
        filtered_group = [line for line in group if some_condition(line)]
        new_sum = len(filtered_group)
        for line in filtered_group:
            line[5] = new_sum
            yield line

with open('C:\AEAtest.csv') as f_in, open('C:\AEAtest_MOD.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in)
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)
    writer.writerows(filter_data(reader))
```

The output was as follows:

```
Jan-20,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,2,more data....

Jan-20,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,2,more data....

Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,7,more data....

Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,7,more data....

Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,7,more data....

Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,7,more data....

Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,7,more data....

Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,7,more data....

Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,7,more data....

Jan-50,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,3,more data....

Jan-50,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,3,more data....

Jan-50,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,3,more data....
```

I am wondering how the extra lines are now occurring, interestingly the last row of text above is row 23 and this is followed by two further blank lines.

Any help with regards to fixing this bug? Kind regards AEA

Comment: Is your CSV file ordered? That is, are you guaranteed that all of the lines for each class appear next to each other, rather than mixed up?

Comment: Hi Blckknght, yes it is ordered so they will appear as above. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: However when a row is deleted it could be from anywhere within each class. I.e. it could be the top pupil or one from in the middle etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use `itertools.groupby` on your csv data, to group by class name. Then, as you go over each group you can correct the count if any lines have been dropped.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def filter_data(data):
    for classname, group in itertools.groupby(data, itemgetter(2)):
        filtered_group = [line for line in group if some_condition(line)]
        new_count = len(filtered_group)
        for line in filtered_group:
            line[5] = new_count
            yield line
```

Here's how you could use it to print the filtered data, given a `some_condition` function:

```
import csv
import random

def some_condition(line):
    return random.random() < 0.5 # delete lines randomly with 50% probability

data = """Jan-20,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,more data....
Jan-20,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,more data....
Jan-20,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,more data....
Jan-20,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,4,more data....
Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,12,more data....
Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,12,more data....
Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,12,more data....
Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,12,more data....
Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,12,more data....
Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,12,more data....
Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,12,more data....
Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,12,more data....
Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,12,more data....
Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,12,more data....
Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,12,more data....
Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,12,more data....
Jan-50,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,6,more data....
Jan-50,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,6,more data....
Jan-50,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,6,more data....
Jan-50,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,6,more data....
Jan-50,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,6,more data....
Jan-50,Data,Class 22zn,2,10yo+,6,more data....""".splitlines()

for line in filter_data(csv.reader(data)):
    print(line)
```

Probably you'll want to be reading and writing actual files, rather than parsing a string and printing the modified results. Here's some (untested) code that shows how you could do that instead:

```
with open('myfile.csv', 'rb') as f_in, open('myfile_filtered.csv', 'wb') as f_out:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in)
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)
    writer.writerows(filter_data(reader))
```

Note that in Python 3, the files should be opened in text mode rather than binary mode, but you also need to pass the extra parameter `newline=""` in order to let the `csv` module handle the line endings itself.

Comment: Thanks so much for the comments, this will really help me reverse engineer the methods you have used and apply through out my code.

Comment: Hi @Blckknght I have managed to get your code to work however it appears to input an extra line in between each line in the output csv. So it appears : 

Jan-20,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,2,more data....

Jan-20,Data,Class xpv,4,11yo+,2,more data....

Jan-30,Data,Class tn2,4,10yo+,7,more data....

Any ideas how to rectify this?

Comment: Well that is just great ^ Comments dont allow blank lines. Any ways I am sure you know what blank lines look like. All the best!

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure from your comment what could be happening. Perhaps you could try playing around with some of the options to `csv.reader` or `csv.writer` to see if you can get them to handle newlines differently?

Comment: I am afraid I couldn't do anything to fix this. :(

Comment: @AEA: Can you edit the question with the remaining issue you're having? I'm afraid I don't entirely understand where the blank lines are turning up. Show the code you're using too!

Comment: Added to the question the code used and the output. Many thanks AEA

Comment: Ah, in Python 3 you need to open the files with the extra parameter `newline=""`, and for Python 2 you need to open in binary mode. I'll update the code in the answer!

Comment: The code is working great in my project, however it is overwriting the name of the row in row 1 i.e. the title. How do I make this code start from row 2 ? Many thanks AEA